# Azure AD application Model

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm wondering about the different types of applications.

What I understand:

- If I add an application via app registration an application object and an service principal is created
- If I consent to an application, only a service principal is created in my tenant , which is a copy of the application object.

If i understand the screenshot correctly only a service principal appears in my tenant.

**However, the fact is if i add an gallery app like twitter i get both i can also open and modify the manifest file like it is "my" application.**

For me it looks like im getting also a copy of the application object which source is the app gallery directory as mentioned here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-how-applications-are-added

Is this the general case when using apps from the gallery?
Can somebody give some insights on that whats happening in the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Gallery Application is not same as Multi-tenant App which are usually used for Azure B2B.**

If I add a gallery App, it will be registered in my tenant and created in my tenant  as App for a single-tenant App (Expect it is Native App and it's default a multi-tenant App).

## For Multi-tenant App:

It is developed and registered from one organization, If the owner make it to multi-tenant, it just need to be created as a Service principal in other tenant. Also, the owner of this multi-tenant App  can use it for Azure AD B2B and can control who can access it, NOT any tenant can use it. The following dig is for Multi-tenant App:

[image]

## For Gallery App :

It has been developed and published by 3rd party and NOT registered for multi-tenant to let the user's tenant use it. Any AAD tenant can add it and use it .

**It means that you can add a Gallery App into your tenant and use it for your own tenant. Not like use a Multi-tenant which has been pre-configured from another tenant.** For your tenant, it’s a new Application. So, it will also be registered in your Tenant.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, @Thomas  Is this answer helpful?